# In Takenoko, when rain falls on a segment that has the fertilizer improvement, how much does the bamboo grow?

Tags: takenoko

In Takenoko, rain specifically causes a selected segment to gain one piece of bamboo - but the fertilizer improvement doubles growth. So how much growth occurs as a result of rainfall on an irrigated segment with the fertilizer improvement?

Comment: NB: There is no Takenoko tag and I don't have enough reputation to create one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is covered in the official FAQ: http://www.jybe.ch/faq/takenoko_faq_eng.pdf

> If the target plot carries a fertilizer improvement, 2 bamboo sections
>   are added to the plot.